# React JS, unable to redirect component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using **hash router**, my redirect function not working as expected.

After user delete a component the below function should redirect to my home page

```
const handledelete=()=>{
        apiService('/d/, "DELETE").then(
         ()=> { <Redirect to='/' />}
        )
      };
```

Desired route

```
  <Route exact path="/" component={SimpleCard}/>
```

Parent element

```
  <HashRouter>
      <Base/>
   </HashRouter>
```

I tried history.push method using with router but did not work

Comment: `<Redirect>` is usually used inside a `<Switch>` to redirect to another page if nothing else matched. To change location programmatically you need to use the `History` object (for +v5 in FC simply use `useHistory()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this hope this help .

```
state = {
redirect : false;
}
const handledelete=()=>{
        apiService('/d/, "DELETE").then(
         ()=> {
              this.setState({redirect:true})
          }
        )
      };


render(){
 if(this.state.redirect)
   <Redirect to="/path"/>
 return(
   <></>
 )

}
```